# Espresso test in an hybrid (Compose + XML) project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

When i run my espresso test (see below) it cannot find a view by a given Text ("FindMeText"). Is it possible to execute some action on a Composable using espresso?
According to android docu it should be possible https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#espresso-interop

full project https://github.com/Remicek/hybridxmlcompose2

But i keep getting an error

> No views in hierarchy found matching: an instance of
> android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without
> transformation to match: is "FindMeText"

I cannot use

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var composeTestRule: ComposeContentTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<UiTestingDemoActivity>()

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        CustomCheckbox()
    }
```

because CustomCheckbox() will have a lot of input params and is initialized already by the activity.

I have a simple setup:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.my_composable).setContent {
            CustomCheckbox()
        }
    }
}
```

Composable:

```
@Composable
fun CustomCheckbox(){
    Row(Modifier.background(color = Color.DarkGray)){
        Button(onClick =  {}){
            Text("FindMeText")
        }
        Checkbox(checked = true, onCheckedChange = {})
    }
}
```

and a espresso test:

```
class MainActivityTest(){
    @get:Rule
    var activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun findTextInComposeViewFail() {
        onView(withText("FindMeText")).perform(click())
    }
}
```